# How to run java program in command prompt by outputting results to log file and also to console

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have a Java Program which needs to be executed from command line where the output should be printed in console and also to a file(log file).

Comment: Are you using any logging framework like log4j?

Comment: You dumped requirements, but what is your question? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: hm! My question is How to print and send console output to a file in a bat script?

Comment: See the link I have in my comment. Your question is way too vague and unspecific. It very much depends on things like: A) what your application is doing B) if you are already using a logging framework ... or if your just doing system.out.print all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Log4j for logging you should setup appropriate appenders for both Console and File output. Also you could use Remote appender.

Here is an example of such appender:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE, CONSOLE, REMOTE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.file=/tmp/logs/log.txt
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.REMOTE=com.holub.log4j.RemoteAppender
log4j.appender.REMOTE.Port=1234
log4j.appender.REMOTE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.REMOTE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Comment: What exactly you use for logging?

Comment: See, if i use this "java -classpath lib\ScriptRunner.jar;lib\ojdbc7.jar;lib\sqljdbc4-2.0.jar;. ExecuteScripts" its just printing console and if i use this"java -classpath lib\ScriptRunner.jar;lib\ojdbc7.jar;lib\sqljdbc4-2.0.jar;. ExecuteScripts > console.log" its jjust writing in file

Comment: I want both in file and console

Comment: That is because "java -classpath lib\ScriptRunner.jar;lib\ojdbc7.jar;lib\sqljdbc4-2.0.jar;. ExecuteScripts > console.log" is explicitly directing output from the console to a file.  Your application is still just writing to the console.  Use something like Log4J to force your application to write to both.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @RiaanNel

Answer (score 0):

"java VerifyDB > VerifyDB.log && type VerifyDB.log"

I found answer
This suites me